# How to make an iso of BLFS 8.4 to distribute

Tags: iso, lfs

I have successfully created BLFS 8.4 and now I want to make its iso file so that I can transfer it to my other laptop like any other Linux distribution such as Ubuntu, Mint, Manjaro, etc. is installed using an iso file.

Comment: There is probably someone with some good insight into this, but I'll share my thoughts... One of the major differences between the various distributions *is* the installation process. As you know, the (B)LFS installation process is to manually build everything from source. To accomplish what you seek is probably going to look more like a restore procedure than a guided *installation*. Then there is the question of hardware support, which you can overcome with a highly generic kernel (or two)... But also, if you've built with optimizations, your binaries may not execute on different hardware.

Comment: There must be some way!

Comment: Or then how do they make and distribute operating systems. I have read somewhere that MacOS X was based on LFS 6.1

Comment: Would it work if I tar up the LFS system and untar it on an empty partition of the target machine?